# Virtuoso Dataset working on one service and not on another

Tags: java, soap, cxf, virtuoso

I have java app with soap services.
I am using Virtuoso and i am facing some strange problem.

The problem is because VirtDataset is working on some service and to another it does not. It is strange because i am using the same function for two services. If I execute the working service then other service work otherwise it does not.

I noticed that if i add this

```
Model model3 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

before VirtDataset connection it works.

```
protected void loadFile(String fileName, String database) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
    VirtDataset virtuosoDataset = new VirtDataset(virtuosoLocation, virtuosoUser, virtuosoPass);

    virtuosoDataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);

    VirtModel model = (VirtModel) virtuosoDataset.getDefaultModel();
    System.out.println(virtuosoDataset.getGraphName());
    model.setBatchSize(10000);
    model.read(reader, ConfigurationFile.getProperty(JENAXMLBASE));
    virtuosoDataset.commit();

    if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.info(new LogMessage("Loading file to database finished. Loaded " + model.size() + " triples.",
                "importModel", "").toString());
    }
    TDBFactory.release(virtuosoDataset);
}
```

Error:

```
 qtp56510351-30] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Application {http://services.ls.example.si/}ServicesImplService#{http://services.ls.example.si/}importModel has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Versions:

Java 1.8

virt_jena3.jar

virtjdbc4.jar

virtuoso server 3.7.2 and 3.8.2

jena 3.6.0

Comment: Several missing details are likely to be important: Virtuoso server version, Virtuoso JDBC Driver version, Virtuoso Jena Provider version, Java version. Please add these to your question.

Comment: You said "virtuoso server 3.7.2 and 3.8.2" -- does this mean that you're running 2 Virtuoso instances, and seeing this issue with one and not the other? If so, which is which? Clarifying my previous -- please provide the first stanza (don't need `Usage` onward) from `virtuoso-t -?` for each Virtuoso instance involved. Please also provide complete output (changing `/path/to` to suit your environment) of `java -jar /path/to/virt_jena3.jar`, `java -jar /path/to/virtjdbc4.jar`, `java -version`, and `sparql --version`. (Yes, details matter; Virtuoso 3.x would be *15+ years* outdated.)